# onClick on button that should reload the page without querystring not working: he reloads the same URL

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a button with onClick attribute that should reload the page without the querystring, but it just reloads the page with the exact same URL.

This is the situation:

page url:

```
http://.../index.php/all-reservations?id_user=0&plate=0&from=2017-09-19&to=
```

the button:

```
<button id="resResetBtn" onclick="location.href='/index.php/all-reservations?view=allreservations'"><?= JTEXT::_('RESET_SEARCH') ?></button>
```

What I get is the button reloads the page with the exact same querystring.
This is what I tried:

- added the http schema to the url
- added a "nocache" param to the new url

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the query string first and then reload the page. Use this line of code

```
window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

Or, alternatively:

```
window.location = window.location.pathname;
```

or even,

```
window.location.replace(location.pathname);
```

Comment: Same result :(. it reloads the page with same url.

Comment: No. Its so strange, its the first time I get this behaviour.

Comment: Try in incognito mode

Comment: Same result. Same behaviour.